Store git-lfs files locally instead of pushing to server on git push
So I want to store large files from a git repository (which is setup to use git-lfs) locally on a backup hard drive instead of pushing the large files to and storing them in a remote server which git lfs does by default. I basically want that backup hard drive to act as the remote server that git lfs uploads to by default.
I have tried doing this:
git config lfs.storage /absolute/path/to/local/storage

However, when I push changes to the remote repository it seems to be trying to upload the large files managed by git-lfs to a remote server, and I get this error:

batch response: This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access.
failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/repoGitLTF.git'

I am not trying to upload the large files to the remote server, just save them locally on the backup hard drive (which is not the same location as the local repository), but otherwise push all other changes to the github remote repository.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I've read the comment you left under my answer and now I understand better what you're trying to achieve. I decided to delete my post as it did not answer your question. I I thought you needed to synchronize your changes on two different remotes (one locally and one on the network). I did not understand you didn't want to purchase more space for the remote on GitHub (my bad). However, I'm posting your comment from my answer as I think it clarifies/helps to understand what you need.

"I want to be able to push all changes to the github repository hosted on github like normal. However, I want to store the large files locally instead of the default location where git lfs uploads them in a live server. Your solution will produces the same error when pushing to the github repository: "This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access."

Yes, and I think the only solutin to this is to host my own storage on localhost server and change where git lfs store the files like this "git config remote.origin.lfsurl http://localhost:3000/username/repo.git/info/lfs" or something.
